# Hibernate composite-map-key

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm have this *.hbm.xml

```
... 
<id name="id" type="java.lang.Integer" column="col1"/>

<map name="myMap" table="table1" cascade="delete" lazy="false">
    <key column="col1" />
    <composite-map-key class="MyCompositeKey">
        <key-property name="komp_key1" column="komp_key1"></key-property>
        <key-property name="komp_key2" column="komp_key2"></key-property>
    </composite-map-key>

    <many-to-many column="col2"  class="MyClass" />
</map>
...
```

In result I have this constraint:

```
CONSTRAINT relations_pkey PRIMARY KEY (entity_id, attribute_idv, entity_val)
```

May I have this constraint:

```
CONSTRAINT relations_pkey PRIMARY KEY (entity_id, attribute_idv, entity_val, col2)
```

Can I add col2 to composite key?